# Volume of a solid(between two planes)?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, volume

> A solid lies between planes perpendicular to the y-axis at $ y=0$ and $y=1$. The cross-sections perpendicular to the y-axis are circular disks with diameters running from the y-axis to the parabola $x=\sqrt{11}y^2$. Find the volume of the solid.

The wording of this question really throws me off, should my integral end up being $\int_0^1 π(\sqrt{11}y^2)^2$. Or am I doing this completely wrong?

Thank you for your input!

Comment: I'd be curious to see someone make a nice Mathematica plot of this.

Comment: Wait what does that mean?

Comment: As in, make a picture in the program Mathematica that displays this solid.

Comment: Oh okay, do you know if my setup is right? Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: @Semiclassical, is [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+z%3Dsqrt%2811y^4%2F4-%28x-sqrt%2811%29y^2%2F2%29^2%29) the plot you are looking for? I've used the equation $$\sqrt{(x-\sqrt{11}y^2/2)^2+z^2}=\sqrt{11}y^2/2$$

Comment: Can't tell from that, honestly. The fact that WA doesn't allow 3D contour plots is annouying. (Though, in this case it might be easier to swap $y$ and $z$ so that it opens upwards.)

Comment: It is easier to visualize by just thinking about it. Comes to a point at the bottom, the left wall is vertical. Vaguely like an upward opening cone. Your suggested integral was almost right, except for an issue of diameter versus radius.

Answer (score 1):

The **diameter** runs from the $y$-axis to the parabola $x=\sqrt{11}y^2$. So the **radius** of cross-section at height $y$ is $\frac{\sqrt{11}y^2}{2}$.

From this radius, you can calculate the area $A(y)$ of cross-section at height $y$, and then find the volume in the usual way.